# Associated Legendre Function

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I am writing Python code which returns the associated Legendre function.
Using numpy poly1d function on this part,

```
firstTerm = (np.poly1d([-1,0,1]))**(m/2.0) # HELP!
```

It yields an error since it can only be raised to integer.

Is there any other alternative where I can raise the desired function to power 1/2 and etc.?

Comment: have you considered using the Legendre polynomials directly: [numpy.polynomials.legendre module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.legendre.html)

Comment: numpy.polynomials.legendre module converts the polynomial to legendre series. What I need is the associated legendre function where the power of a non-integer appears to be the problem.

Comment: Any of these what you're after http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html#legendre-functions?

Comment: What I am actually looking for is getting associated Legendre function using numpy.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't raise your `poly1d` to half-integer power is that that would not be a polynomial, since it would contain square roots.

While in principle you could orthogonalize the functions yourself, or construct the functions from something like [`sympy.special.legendre`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.legendre.html), but your safest bet is symbolic math. And hey, we already have [`sympy.functions.special.polynomials.assoc_legendre`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/functions/special.html#sympy.functions.special.polynomials.assoc_legendre)! Since symbolic math is slow, you should probably use `sympy.lambdify` to turn each function into a numerical one:

```
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols('x')
n = 3
m = 1
legfun_sym = sym.functions.special.polynomials.assoc_legendre(n,m,x)
legfun_num = sym.lambdify(x,legfun_sym)

print(legfun_sym)
print(legfun_num)
x0 = 0.25
print(legfun_sym.evalf(subs={x:x0}) - legfun_num(x0))
```

This prints

```
-sqrt(-x**2 + 1)*(15*x**2/2 - 3/2)
<function <lambda> at 0x7f0a091976e0>
-1.11022302462516e-16
```

which seems to make sense (the first is the symbolic function at `x`, the second shows that `lambdify` indeed creates a `lambda` from the function, and the last one is the numerical difference of the two functions at the pseudorandom point `x0 = 0.25`, and is clearly zero within machine precision).

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot thanks for the fix! I had no idea I had python 2 answers lying around, I'll have to check my older posts thoroughly and get rid of those...